# Why isnt my custom post type not showing on the frontend navigation menu

Tags: wordpress

I have created a custom post type, and it shows on the backend ... {appearance > menus}

When I add it to the list of my navigation menus, it does not show on the front end. I am really confused why it doesn't show. I doubled check my labels and args for register_post_type, and they all seem to be correct.

Below is my code. Any help would be really appreciated!

```
<?php


function mtl_register_todo(){

    $singular_name = apply_filters("mtl_label_single","Todo");
    $plural_name = apply_filters("mtl_label_single","Todos");


    $labels = [

        "name"=> $plural_name,
        "singular_name"=> $singular_name,
        "add_new"       => "Add new",
        "add_new_item"  => "Add new ". $singular_name,
        "edit"          => "Edit",
         "edit_item"    => "Edit ". $singular_name,
        "new_item"      => "New ". $singular_name,
        "view"          => "View",
        "view_item"     => "View " . $plural_name,
        "search_items"  => "Search ". $plural_name,
        "not_found"     => "No ". $plural_name . " found",
        "not_found_in_trash" => "",
        "menu_name"         => $plural_name


    ];


    $args = apply_filters("mtl_todo_args",[

        "labels"        =>$labels,
        "description"   => "Todo's categories",
        "taxonomies"    => ["category"],
        "public"        => TRUE,
        "show_in_menu" => TRUE,
        "position"      => 5,
        "menu_icon"    =>"dashicons-edit",
        "show_in_nav_menus" => TRUE,
        "query_var"=> TRUE,
        "can_export"    => true,
        "rewrite"    => ["slug"=>"todo"],
        "capability_type"  => "post",
        "supports"   =>  [

            "title"


        ]



    ]);


    //Register post type

    register_post_type("todo",$args);


}

add_action("init","mtl_register_todo");
```

Comment: Make sure you enable your post type from 'Screen options'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while creating Custom post type in WordPress. My posts were showing 404 and then I realise that my permalinks are not set properly, it was on default day and name. Just switch it to Post name and you should be fine.

Answer (score -2):

make sure you have following array entries set:

```
'show_ui'               => true,
'show_in_menu'          => true,
'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
```